# How to wait until all stores are Sync in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, promise, gridpanel, extjs-stores

I have a list of grids that can change their data in form by end-user.
Finally, I want to sync all the grids by clicking the button, then an operation is performed.

I wrote the code below:

```
$.when.apply(
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')
       .forEach(function(item) {
             if (item.getXType() == "grid") {
                if (item.store.getNewRecords().length > 0 || item.store.getUpdatedRecords().length > 0 || item.store.getRemovedRecords().length > 0) {
                    item.store.sync();
                 }
             }
})).then(function (results) {
    //do something
});
```

Problem is here that `store.sync()` not waiting for callback.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: `store.sync()` should not be required, to begin with... use config `autoSync: true`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have alot of data in grid and dont want to send request for each cell edit.

Comment: it would only sync the one row, which had changed - while a user won't change more than one row at a time - this barely would be more traffic, only split into more requests. in times, where people tend to have > 100mbit/s, even at home.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I do it with `Promise` , Anyway thank you.

Comment: @MartinZeitler `autoSync` changes the behaviour of the program. Not sure why you recommend that. Would you want Excel to automatically save all your changes without asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do it with `Promise` like this:

```
 // Sync grid data if exist dirty data
 Promise.all(
     Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')
     .map(grid => grid.getStore())
     .filter(s => (s.getNewRecords().length + s.getUpdatedRecords().length + s.getRemovedRecords().length) > 0)
     .map(s => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           s.sync({
               success: () => { resolve(); },
               failure: () => { reject(); }
           });
      }))
      ).then(() => {
           //do something
      });
```

Comment: From here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?470722-How-to-wait-until-all-stores-are-Sync-in-ExtJs&p=1320926&viewfull=1#post1320926

Comment: @EvanTrimboli :( Yes.I asked this question at there,too

Comment: Just some attribution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `callback` for your [`store.sync()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.data.ProxyStore.html#method-sync) method.

> The **callback** function to be called upon completion of the sync. The callback is called regardless of success or failure and is passed the following parameters: (batch, options).

You could achieve your requirement like this

1. Take a blank array name before loop. like this `var gridIds=[]`.
2. In side of loop before `store.sync()` push grid id in above array.
3. Now in `callback` function remove that grid id from above array and check condition array is blank then your all store sync response has came.

You can check here with working **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2lf9)**

**Note** I have used dummy api. Please use your actual api.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('MyStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

            alias: 'store.mystore',

            fields: ['name'],

            autoLoad: true,

            pageSize: 25,

            remoteSort: true,

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'POST',
                api: {
                    read: 'data.json',
                    update: 'your_update_api',
                    create: 'your_create_api',
                    destroy: 'your_delete_api'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    encode: true,
                    root: 'data'
                }
            },
        });

        Ext.define('MyGrid', {

            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

            alias: 'widget.mygrid',

            store: {
                type: 'mystore'
            },

            height: 200,

            border: true,

            tools: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
                tooltip: 'Add New Record',
                handler: function () {
                    let grid = this.up('grid'),
                        store = grid.getStore();

                    store.insert(0, {
                        name: 'Test ' + (store.getCount() + 1)
                    });
                }
            }],
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1
            }]
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            // title: 'Store sync example',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'mygrid',
                title: 'Grid 1'
            }, {
                xtype: 'mygrid',
                title: 'Grid 2'
            }, {
                xtype: 'mygrid',
                title: 'Grid 3'
            }, {
                xtype: 'mygrid',
                title: 'Grid 4'
            }],

            bbar: ['->', {
                text: 'Submit Changes',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var panel = btn.up('panel'),
                        grids = panel.query('grid'),
                        gtidIds = [],
                        lenthCheck = function (arr) {
                            return arr.length > 0;
                        };

                    grids.forEach(function (grid) {
                        let store = grid.getStore();
                        if (lenthCheck(store.getNewRecords()) || lenthCheck(store.getUpdatedRecords()) || lenthCheck(store.getRemovedRecords())) {
                            panel.mask('Please wait...');
                            gtidIds.push(grid.getId());
                            store.sync({
                                callback: function () {
                                    Ext.Array.remove(gtidIds, grid.getId());
                                    if (gtidIds.length == 0) {
                                        panel.unmask();
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'All grid store sync success.');
                                    }
                                }
                            }, grid);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. but it's not what i looking for , because i need do something after all `grid.store.sync()`

Comment: Yes it's same you can manage after all `store.sync`. I think go through with fiddle and debug the code. Because inside of callback I have checked condition that if all `store.sync` response has came then we can put our logic whatever we want.

Comment: True. thank you but I think `Promise` is better idea. No?